# How to individual print every word of a sentence in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose select 10tag but when i display this tag individually how can i do this?

[how can i print all tag individual as like C, C#, Java , PHP, Python, .net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqN2Q.png)
this is link of my pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqN2Q.png

Comment: You need to use CSS styling.

Comment: what you tried so far? add some code what you tried so that anyone can answer correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question and your question's heading isn't that  clear to me. 

 if you want to take all word from a string then here is your code

```
<?php

    $sentence = "my name is xyz";
    $store = explode(" ",$sentence); // this will output an array of words
    print_r($store);

?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array ( [0] => my
        [1] => name
        [2] => is 
        [3] => xyz
      )
```

and if you want to show the words as your picture then this may help you(though i don't use any anchor tag here, i am just showing u the way, you should further stylize it to look like your picture):

```css
 body {
  background:pink; 
 }

 ul{
    
 }
 ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 background: green;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 120px;
 text-align: center;
 color:#fff;
 }
 ul li:hover{
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
 }
 nav{
     width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;

 }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 
</head>
<body>

 <nav>
         <ul>
             <li>C</li>
             <li>C#</li>
             <li>Java</li>
             <li>PHP</li>
             <li>Python</li>
             <li>.Net</li>
         </ul>
 </nav>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: thanks dear!
problem solved

Comment: if u find my solution useful then kindly up vote it , it's a good manner.